# Pylint keeps giving me an error on line 1 where my imports are

Tags: python, syntax, pylint

```
import os
import json
import six
from dotenv import dotenv
from google.cloud import translate



#Translates english to french
# Initialize Translation client
def english_to_french(english_text="Hello", project_id="ferrous-amphora-352613"):
    """Translating Text."""

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

    location = "global"

    parent = f"projects/{ferrous-amphora-352613}/locations/{My First Project}"

    # Translate text from English to French
    response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "contents": [text],
            "mime_type": "text/plain",  # 
            "source_language_code": "en-US",
            "target_language_code": "fr",
        }
    )

    # Display the translation for each input text provided
    for translation in response.translations:
        print("Translated text: {}".format(translation.translated_text))



# Translates french to english
# Initialize Translation client
def english_to_french(french_text="Bonjour", project_id="ferrous-amphora-352613"):
    """Translating Text."""

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

    location = "global"

    parent = f"projects/{ferrous-amphora-352613}/locations/{My First Project}"

    # Translate text from English to French
    response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "contents": [french_text],
            "mime_type": "text/plain",  # 
            "source_language_code": "fr",
            "target_language_code": "en",
        }
    )

    # Display the translation for each input text provided
    for translation in response.translations:
        print("Translated text: {}".format(translation.translated_text))


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        pass
```

I keep getting an error where the import os is, but everything is looks ok. Can someone look at my syntax and help me, been stuck on this for days

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple imports on the same line:

```
import os import json import six from dotenv import dotenv from google.cloud import translate
```

They should be either separated onto individual lines or separated by commas, e.g:

```
import os, json, six
from dotenv import dotenv
```

Comment: Imports should be on separate lines, not separated by commas.   [Reference here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports)

Comment: Look at the formatted code. Imports are on separate lines.

Comment: @MashCode20 - were the multiple imports on one line? If not, my answer won't help.

Comment: @geektechstuff originally they were but changed it to multiple lines. right now I tried to run pylint again and its still giving me an error like this: translator.py:1:9: E0001: invalid syntax (<fstring>, line 1) (syntax-error)

Comment: Ok, make sure to check out the link from @S3DEV as I had not considered PEP8 standards.

Comment: @S3DEV Thank you for sharing the reference documentation, fixed the import error.

Comment: @geektechstuff, thanks for the pointers about the import separation, I was looking on some of my old projects and realized that I had some on the same line without indentation.